How to find the value of x given a y in Seaborn lineplot
As the title says, I want to obtain the value of x given a y in a Seaborn lineplot.
I have the following plot:
sns.lineplot(y=outlier_percent, x=np.linspace(0.001, 3, 50))

Where outlier_percent is just a list of values.
And I want to the value of the x axis for a y = 10. Is there a straight method or maybe a way to obtain the value of the intersection with a horizontal line like the following:
plt.hlines(y=10, xmin=0, xmax=3, color='red')

Thanks!


If outlier_percent is strictly monotone increasing, you can use np.interp(...). You can use -outlier_percent and -10 for a decreasing array.
